# frequently getting stale alerts for Datanodes

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ambari, namenode, datanode

I am getting stale alerts every hr, if the last point of contact between Data nodes and Namenode is more than 30 s we get these alerts.

I am not able to find the root cause of this slowness, I have 32 cores system, but when this alert is generated in htop hdfs usage is more but not all cores are 100% utilized.

DataNode Health Summary

DataNode Health: [Live=5, Stale=1, Dead=0]
Please suggest changes required to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot tell you why *you* are getting a stale datanode. It could be a networking issue. It could be a node that has hardware starting to fail. It could just be that you need to tweak the [configuration parameters](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-to-identify-stale-datanode/td-p/96336#:%7E:text=When%20a%20datanode%20is%20stale,a%20datanode%20is%20considered%20dead).